# Como funciona a comunicação serial e como fazer utilizando C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, linux, qt, serial

Utilizo o **Debian 7.1** e preciso fazer comunicação serial entre um computador e um microcontrolador utilizando **C/C++**. Já pesquisei bastante sobre o assunto, mas os artigos e exemplos que encontrei são muito confusos, pouco claros e pouco personalizáveis.

Gostaria de entender como funciona a comunicação serial, se possível a nível de hardware e sistema operacional, bem como entender como posso implementá-la em **C/C++** ou alguma outra linguagem de baixo/médio nível (Para que eu possa entender a integração com o hardware e o sistema operacional de forma detalhada).

Não estou pedindo códigos prontos (embora códigos fossem de grande ajuda), mas orientações de como devo proceder para fazê-lo e uma explicação de como funciona este processo. Pode ser através de uma API ou biblioteca.

Comment: Nunca experimentei fazer programacao para comunicacao serial, mas, se sabes ingles, o [Serial Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/) talvez ajude alguma coisa.

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma lida. Isto com certeza vai ser de grande ajuda.

Comment: Este link é uma boa referência pra comunicação com porta serial usando Boost.Asio: http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A explicação com o nível de detalhamento que você está buscando levaria horas para ser formulada. Talvez o melhor seja investigar o material que as outras pessoas estão recomendando.

Uma solução rápida em C++ seria utilizar uma biblioteca pronta para ler/escrever na serial. Se isso for aceitável para você, o [framework do Qt](http://qt.io) traz uma **solução multi-plataforma** para comunicação serial bem interessante.

A documentação do Qt oferece um exemplo chamado [**Terminal**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-terminal-example.html), que mostra como identificar as portas seriais no computador, conectar a uma delas e imprimir os dados no console. Infelizmente, esse exemplo apresenta uma GUI (*Graphical User Interface*) e isso faz com que o código de exemplo se torne um pouquinho inchado.

Alguns meses atrás decidi remover toda essa parte de UI e acabei disponibilizando um exemplo mais simples e enxuto no GitHub chamado [**QtSerial**](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/QtSerial).

**Basicamente, o processo para ler de uma porta serial usando o Qt consiste em:**

- **Listar as portas seriais do computador**: a classe [`QSerialPortInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialportinfo.html) oferece métodos estáticos para isso e fornece informações sobre cada porta serial encontrada, como localização, identificação do fabricante, identificação do produto, etc.
- **Conectar a uma porta serial**: basta instânciar um objeto do tipo [`QSerialPort`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) configurar alguns itens como: o nome da porta, o *baud rate*, se tem paridade ou não, o tipo do controle de fluxo e outras coisinhas mais.
- **Ler da porta serial**: para realizar esta tarefa você precisa monitorar 2 *signals* do objeto `QSerialPort` instânciado: `readyRead()` e `error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)`. Para fazer isso você deve declarar uma subclasse de `QObject` e implementar os dois 2 *slots* que irão ser acionados automaticamente quando estes *signals* acontecerem.

Em outras palavras, `readyRead()` é o sinal enviado pelo objeto `QSerialPort` quando há dados da serial para serem recebidos pelo seu programa. O sinal `error()`, é claro, é emitido apenas em caso de falha durante a comunicação.

Uma operação essencial para garantir o sucesso da leitura é invocar `setDataTerminalReady(true)`. Há varias perguntas no SO de pessoas que não conseguem fazer a leitura funcionar corretamente porque esqueceram de chamar este método.

Bom, para fazer o inverso e enviar dados pela serial o processo é mais fácil. Basta ajustar a chamada do método `QSerialPort::open()` para solicitar permissão de leitura e escrita na porta serial:

```
serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

Para enviar dados, execute `QSerialPort:write()` ou `QSerialPort:putChar()`. **Entretanto**, `write()` não bloqueia a execução e por isso retorna imediatamente. Assim, quando os dados são efetivamente enviados pela porta serial o *signal* `bytesWritten()` é emitido. Então não esqueça de implementar um *slot* para conectar a este sinal e garantir que tudo que o seu programa tentou enviar realmente foi submetido para a serial.

Bem, testei o [QtSerial](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/QtSerial) com mais de um Arduino e com outros dispositivos. Por gentileza, faça um ***fork*** do meu repositório e ao encontrar problemas neste aplicativo solicite um [`pull request`](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/). Ficarei feliz em adicionar suas mudanças neste projeto.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito grato pela resposta, era algo assim que estava procurando. Testarei a sua aplicação e o exemplo que o Qt oferece durante as próximas semanas.

Answer (score 5):

Aparentemente você está perguntando sobre a implementação da comunicação serial, em vez de perguntar simplesmente como se usa.

Bom, pra isso recomendo um bom livro de drivers Linux, recomendo o [Linux Device Drivers](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), especificamente o [capítulo sobre TTY drivers](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch18.pdf) deve ser do seu interesse.

[A quarta edição deste livro está a caminho](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030867.do).

Em relação a hardware, [a página em inglês da wikipédia referente ao padrão RS-232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) e a [página sobre portas seriais](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port) tem bastante informações. Outra com bastante informação a respeito [está no wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming).

Se no final das contas você não deseja entrar neste nível de detalhes (o que seria desnecessário para realizar uma simples comunicação com um dispositivo), siga os links passados para você nos comentários da sua pergunta, [este é mais um](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios).

Answer (score 3):

A questão é meio complicada.

Na teoria ler e gravar numa porta serial é igual ler/gravar qualquer outro arquivo; a diferença é o nome dele ( /dev/ttyS0 para a primeira serial, /dev/ttyS1 para a segunda e por aí vai).

O problema mesmo é configurar a comunicação antes de enviar/receber os dados; eu gosto de configurar via termios mas já ví aplicativos que chamam o próprio setserial via system() para configurar antes de abrir a porta.

Dê uma olhada em [Linux Serial programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Linux).